# ¿Con qué criterio aparece la notificación para animar el voto?

Tags: soporte, notificaciones

Ya hace unos días que he notado que a veces al entrar en alguna pregunta de Stack Overflow, aparece la siguiente notificación:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> Welcome back! If you found this question useful,
> don't forget to vote both the question and the answers up.

Como veis, anima al votar tanto la pregunta como la respuesta si ha sido de ayuda.

¿Qué os parece esta idea? ¿Podríamos añadir algo así en este nuestro sitio en español? ¿O ya está implementado y yo no lo he visto?

Comment: edité un poco la pregunta porque sí está implementado. Si te parece mal, revierte sin problema!

Comment: @fedorqui perfecto, por supuesto. No sabía que ya estaba activo en toda la red, nunca lo ví aqui en [es.so]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta notificación es común a toda la red Stack Exchange y aparece si se cumplen todas estas condiciones:

- no has estado en el sitio las últimas 24 horas
- tienes una cookie válida en ese sitio
- tienes más de 15 puntos reputación en ese sitio
- llegas a la pregunta desde un buscador
- previamente no has votado ni la pregunta ni a ninguna de las respuestas

fuente: [Disable “don't forget to vote” message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89059/209901).

Veo que [está en traducir.win](https://traducir.win/string/5716), por lo que debería mostrarse a todos los usuarios de Stack Overflow en español que cumplan este requisito. ¿Alguien es capaz de no entrar en 24 horas para probarlo? :-)

Actualizo: yo lo hice y no me apareció notificación alguna, pero algo debí hacer mal porque [Nicolas comenta en The Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48787883#48787883) que sí está activo:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ehmm...me estas diciendo que esto está activo al menos desde 2011? Porque no recuerdo verlo nunca hasta muy recientemente. Se habrán cambiado estas condiciones recientemente quiza?

Comment: A mí me sale de vez en cuando, pero tengo mala memoria y no recuerdo cuándo lo vi por primera vez jaja. Lo que sí veo es que la gente no parece estar muy contenta con la barrita esta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notification-bar y muchos piden que se quite o se endurezcan las condiciones. A mí particularmente me molesta un poco que me salga en sitios tipo [unix.se], donde accedo un par de veces por semana.

Comment: Yo tambien tengo mala memoria, y probablemente algo de déficit de atencion, así que es posible que haya estando saliéndome toda la vida y no me haya dado cuenta hasta ahora... :|

Comment: No creo que sea eso @Pikoh, a mi tampoco me ha salido nunca en este sitio y casi seguro que en Stackoverflow en inglés tampoco.

Comment: @blonfu a mi en SO si (como ves en la captura), pero aqui nunca

Comment: Oye pues @Pikoh tendré que darte la razón: desde el viernes que no entraba al sitio, he intentado cumplir todos los requisitos que detallo en mi respuesta... y al entrar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/158365/83 desde un buscador no me ha salido aviso alguno. Le consultaré a Nicolas.

Comment: Nicolas está con ello: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48737131#48737131